# Mudar texto em campo select com woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

Gostaria de saber como posso mudar o "botão" de "escolha uma opção" para "escolha um tamanho". Conforme a imagem a baixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc tem acesso ao FTP onde estão os arquivos do site?

Comment: tenho sim, no caso não sei com encontrar o arquivo especifico

Comment: Talvez se colocar todo o código fonte desta página que vc postou a imagem, seja possível verificar.

Comment: não consegui copiar ... passou do limite,... mas vc pode pegar nesse link.. se possivel pfv...
https://www.tortugashoes.com/produto/catamaran-corchoyblanco/

esta online

Comment: Lá na página, abra o console (F12) e execute este comando: `document.getElementById('pa_tamanho').options[0].innerHTML = "Escolha um tamanho";`. Um paliativo seria você colocar esse script no final do arquivo "index" da pasta "/produtos", até que vc descubra onde altera isso no HTML do seu site.

Answer (score 0):

Como não publicou códigos vou dar a minha ajuda como posso, uma boa forma é usar o `f12` do teclado e em seguida precionar este icon: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de pressionar esse icon clique na `combobox`(escolha uma opção), e vai aparecer o código da `combobox` algo como a imagem em baixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa zona do código identifique o nome "escolha uma opção" e substitua por "escolha um tamanho". **Se resultou agora apenas precisa de procurar isso na sua página web local onde está a trabalhar nela, que têm a mesma estrutura de código.**

As imagens são apenas para ajudar a identificar as coisas não são uma recriação exata.

> **ATENÇÃO**: se quer uma resposta mais detalhada deve adicionar o código da página a pergunta.

Comment: bom... e como salvo isso para aparecer sempre.. quando aperto f5 volta como estava,

Comment: @J.Gualberto não prestou atenção a resposta completa, tem agora de identificar esse mesmo código no ficheiro da página local. passei para negrito a frase.

Comment: Muito obrigado... então esse eh o ponto... nao sei como chegar lá... como dito anteriormente.. sou muito iniciante nisso...
vc pode ajudar?

Comment: @J.Gualberto não tem acesso ao código da página?

Comment: se vc fala Cpanel, tenho sim... mas nao localizo essa parte nos arquivos

Comment: @J.Gualberto quando pressiona f12 aparece um tab a dizer "sources" de lado tem uma lista de todos os ficheiros usados na sua página, veja os nomes um a um e procure depois esses arquivos, a melhor coisa a fazer é publicar aqui o código da página para a gente te poder ajudar com mais precisão

Comment: não consegui copiar ... passou do limite,...
mas vc pode pegar nesse link.. se possivel pfv... https://www.tortugashoes.com/produto/catamaran-corchoyblanco/